# Animating RasterStack layers using tmap_animation

Tags: r, animation, raster, r-sf, tmap

I have been attempting to animate a raster stack using `tmap::tmap_animation()`. Each layer covers the exact same geographic extent, but a different date. The output GIF animation is a single frame with multiple small plots.

**Is it possible to create a gif animation of RasterStack using `tmap`?**

The only workaround I have found is to:

1. convert each layer to an SF object
2. give each new `sf` polygon object an attribute 'layer' representing the RasterStack layer it was pulled from
3. `rbind` the `sf` objects together

Once completing the above steps it is possible to plot a gif animation, but it is painfully slow.

Answer (score 3):

`tmap` can plot rasterstacks or rasterbricks as animations directly. The simplest way is to specify `tm_facets()` to restrict the number of rows and columns in each frame  to 1, which stops it creating small multiples, e.g.:

```
library(raster)
library(tmap)

a <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
b <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
c <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
d <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))

my_stack <- stack(a, b, c, d)

anim <- tm_shape(my_stack) + tm_raster() + tm_facets(nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

tmap_animation(anim, "anim_file.gif")
```

Comment: Thank you - I just tried your suggestion and it is a working solution to my issue.